# Test the first 3 chars in a looong string (efficiently)

Tags: shell

If I store a long string in a variable and need to test if the string would begin with the letters abc, what would be the most efficient way to test this?

Of course, you could echo the string and pipe it to grep/awk/sed or something like that but isn't there a more efficient way (which doesn't require to scan the whole string?)?

Can I use a case statement for this, like e.g.

```
case $var in
    ^abc) doSomething;;
esac
```

?

Greets, Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` doesn't really need to scan the whole string. Just use `echo "$string" | grep '^abc'`.

If you really want efficiency, don't use a shell script.

Comment: +1 That's a good point. I think I'll stick to that and see if performance is actually a problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, there's a substring operator:

```
mystring="abcdef blah blah blah"

first_three=${mystring:0:3}
```

after which `$first_three` will contain "abc".

Answer (score 1):

This should be efficient :

```
if [[ "$a" == abc* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case "$var" in
  abc*) doSomething ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

using shell internals is the more efficient way than calling external commands

```
case "$string" in
  abc* ) echo "ok";;
esac
```

Or if you have modern shell such as bash

```
if [ "${string:0:3}" = "abc" ] ;then
   echo "ok"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use grep:

```
if [ ! -z `echo $string | grep '^abc'` ]
```

but for variety you cut use cut

```
if [ `echo $string | cut -c 1-3` = "abc" ]
```